# Why are these resulting symmetric encryption values different?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using something like this:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SSNKey
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE SSNCert;
UPDATE 
    Customers
SET 
    SSNEncrypted = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('SSNKey'), 'DecryptedSSN')
```

Where SSNEncrypted is a varbinary column.  I noticed the values come out different each time. Why is this? And what can I do to get consistent encrypted values, so I can compare them in different tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "by design".

The function `EncryptByKey` is [nondeterministic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_algorithm).

But if you decrypt the different values you always get the original decrypted value.

Have a look at [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/raulga/2006/03/12/indexing-encrypted-data/) blog on MSDN.